# Pushed to origin/master. How to revert

Tags: git, github

The master is a protected branch from GitHub, so I figured this could never happen but I was wrong. There is no pull request to revert on github.

So I thought instead of branching from local master that branching from origin/master would save me a step. This branch that is branched off origin/master is called `feature-x`

I made two commits (SHAs  718016d and 8ab1912 in that order). Then I did a `git pull && git push` which seemingly  merged origin/master into my branch and pushed into origin/master.  There were about ~40 commits difference from the time I branched until I did a git pull.

How can I completely remove the 2 commits from origin/master history? I read that removing commits which has been public is a super bad idea but this is my ideal solution. If someone could suggest how I might go about doing this in a safe way.

If this technique should be avoided;

How can I revert these commits locally and push back into origin/master?  I looked into `git revert` but I want to make sure before I mess things up again that I know exactly whats going on

Added log:

`git pub` is an aliases

```
pub = "!f() { git push -u ${1:-origin} `git symbolic-ref HEAD`; }; f"
```

```
C:\source\ [feature-x ↓1 ↑1 +6 ~8 -0 !]> git add -A; git commit -m "wip"
[feature-x 718016d8a] wip
 14 files changed, 358 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
------Lines removed for anonomity-------
C:\source\ [feature-x ↓1 ↑2]> git pub
To https://github.com/*********
 ! [rejected]            feature-x -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/********.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
C:\source\ [feature-x ↓1 ↑2]> git pull
remote: Counting objects: 331, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (118/118), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (331/331), 88.21 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.sed 0Receiving objects:  27% (90/331)

Resolving deltas: 100% (254/254), completed with 78 local objects.
From https://github.com/********
------Lines removed for anonomity-------
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
------Lines removed for anonomity-------
 27 files changed, 190 insertions(+), 44 deletions(-)
------Lines removed for anonomity-------
C:\source\ [feature-x ↑3]> git pub
Counting objects: 54, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
Writing objects: 100% (54/54), 7.41 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 54 (delta 42), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (42/42), completed with 28 local objects.
Branch feature-x set up to track remote branch master from origin.
To https://github.com/*********
```

Comment: "seemingly" -> include log output. If you were on a branch and did a `git pull` (no other parameter), that command pulls the origin version of *that branch* into the local version of *that branch*. A `git push` similarly works on the current branch. It is unclear as to what you actually did.

Comment: @crashmstr if OP created the branch from `origin/master`, then that's what the branch will track and push/pull with.

Comment: @Quentin yes, if they created a new branch and set it active, made their commits on that branch, and made no reference to origin/master in the `push` or `pull` commands, then yes: they would have changes only on that new branch and origin/master would not be changed by these actions.

Comment: @Quentin I see what you are implying: if they set their *new branch* to track origin/master, then yes. But I don't think that one would normally do this or that one could do this without passing additional parameters. The normal process is for `feature-x` to have its upstream set to `origin/feature-x`.

Comment: Log of git bash added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to revert commits from git :

1.Remove it from history completely using `git rebase -i HEAD~<number_of_commits_from_top_u_want_to_modify>`. This will open a window and will list down the commits. Here, simply remove the lines containing the unwanted commits. Then save and quit. But as you have suggested, this is a bad idea as it modifies the git history and it will require you to force push the branch (as this is not an additive change). But if you do that, it would look like as-if those 2 commits were never there.

2.Use `git revert <commit_id>`. This is the safest option you can chose. This does not actually remove any commits. This simply adds a new commit with exactly undoing what the commit has done and creates a fresh commit. This does not affect the history. This is an additive change so, it does not require force push.

Comment: Do I have to revert all the commits in the merge, or just my commits

Comment: @LearningJrDev how many extra(unwanted) commits were pushed to master? BTW can you provide the exact commands you used from creation of local branch to pushing it?